# PHP datediff february issues

Tags: php, datediff

I'm using a code to find how many days have passed since the new year (January 1). 
I use this code:

```
$newyear = new DateTime("2017-01-01"); // January 1, 2017.
$today = new DateTime(); // March 6, 2017.
$difference = $newyear->diff($today);
```

Now, if I use this code, it shows the right number of days,

```
echo $difference->format("%a days"); // 64 days
```

but when I use a different format, it goes wrong.

```
echo $difference->format("%m months %d days"); // 2months 2 days.
```

I assume this is due to PHP counting February as 31 days long, so technically it is 31 + 31 + 2 days. I want it to count February as 28 or 29 days long, depending on the leap year condition. I guess there must be something in php.ini related to this. What and where to change or is there any hack?

Comment: Thing from the other way: What should `format()` do if `"%m months %d days"` is given. This `1 month with 28 days 1 month with 29 days 2 days`?? You have to count it by hand and format it by yourself:-)

Comment: it's working fine:- https://eval.in/748856

Comment: @Anant I have `2 months 2 days` too, seems that some configuration comes in place. Ignore my first comment. :-)

Comment: @Anant - I wish for the same result. Must be somewhere in the configurations.

Comment: @JustOnUnderMillions  you can check on any version here:- http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/    it outputing same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To debug this issue with PHP incorrectly reporting difference between 2 dates we first must check a few things.

I see a few people are getting mixed results, to debug this try find out what version of the timezonedb you have

```
<?php
echo timezone_version_get();
?>
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.timezone-version-get.php

The PECL timezonedb site can be found at https://pecl.php.net/package/timezonedb

Check to see that you have the most up to date version.

Comment: This solves my problem. Thank you. This is exactly what I was looking for. My upvote doesn't show due to low reputation points.